# How do I check if core data class is nil. in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, if-statement, core-data

I have created an Entity called `Status` with an attribute called `statusUpdate`. I want the user to be able to create a status for the first time which would then be saved in core data, then when the status is next updated to save over the old status in core data. Here is what i've done:

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Status", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Status")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &self.error)

if results?.count > 0 {
    for result: AnyObject in results! {
        if var oldStatus = result.valueForKey("statusUpdate") as? String {
            println("Current User fetched status from Core Data")
            var newStatus = self.updateStatusText.text
            result.setValue(newStatus, forKey: "statusUpdate")
        } else if result.valueForKey("statusUpdate") == nil {
            var newStatus = self.updateStatusText.text
            newUser.setValue(newStatus, forKey: "statusUpdate")
            println("Status uploaded for the first time")
        }
    }
}

context.save(&self.error)
```

The problem is the `else if` seems to always run. I want it to basically only run of the `Status` entity is nil (so it will only run for the first time somebody updates a status) and then when the status is updated after that it will run just the regular `if` statement.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you explicitly check if  (var oldStatus = result.valueForKey("statusUpdate") as? String) == nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 3 of your code inserts a new `Status` object, so each time this code is executed, you are adding an extra object.  The newly inserted object will have a `statusUpdate` of nil (most likely).

When you execute the fetch, in line 6, this new `Status` object will be included in the `results`, together with any objects you have saved previously. So when you iterate through all the `results`, there will always be one for which `statusUpdate` is nil.

I would restructure your code to do the fetch first, establish whether there are any results.  If so, update the `statusUpdate`; if not, create the new object and set the `statusUpdate` field.  Something like this:

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Status")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &self.error)

if let resultsArray = results { // explicitly test for nil results
    if resultsArray.count > 0 {
        // count should be at most one, but just in case we will iterate through:
        for result: AnyObject in resultsArray {
            println("Current User fetched status from Core Data")
            var newStatus = self.updateStatusText.text
            result.setValue(newStatus, forKey: "statusUpdate")
        }
    else { // resultsArray is empty, so insert a new object
        var newStatus = self.updateStatusText.text
        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Status", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newUser.setValue(newStatus, forKey: "statusUpdate")
        println("Status uploaded for the first time")
    }
} else { // fetch returned nil, so log an error:
    println("Nil returned by fetch")
}    
context.save(&self.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (var oldStatus = result.valueForKey("statusUpdate") as? String) != nil{

        println("Current User fetched status from Core Data")
        var newStatus = self.updateStatusText.text
        result.setValue(newStatus, forKey: "statusUpdate")


    }else {

        var newStatus = self.updateStatusText.text
        newUser.setValue(newStatus, forKey: "statusUpdate")
        println("Status uploaded for the first time")
    }
```